# Stop Divs text from overlapping

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Does anyone know how I can stop two divs from overlapping?

I have a .box.active div however the text on this is overlapping into another div

thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Please add just as much code as needed in a snippet here so others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Either you set `display: none` to the elements or you show us the full code to provide a better solution. ;)

Comment: _“Does anyone know how I can stop two divs from overlapping?”_ - by not doing whatever you did to get them to overlap in the first place (which they would not do by themselves.) We have no way whatsoever of telling what you might have done, with the info you have given us so far. Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If DIVS are overlapping then the general principles is your code has made them do that in the first place. Add position relative to the classes on your div tags to start with along with Display block.

```
.yourdivclass {display:block}
.yourdivclass {display:inline-block}
```

Some other possibilities:

- Set widths on elements?
- Have you used FLEX? This can cause this often if your code has not been completed correctly?

Generally, we need more code to solve issues so if this does not help - provide some code in your question and I can help further.

Hope this helps.